# How to create installer with custom action in vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project, custom-action

VS2010 has a Setup Project template, I want to use it to create my setup package. Below are what I have done:

1. Create a Setup Project.
2. In the FileSystem Panel, right click Application Folder, Select Add -> File, then select my dll. The dll and its dependency dll are added.
3. Create a Class Library, and add an Installer class to it.
4. In the Installer Class, add my logical code.
5. Add the Class Library as Project Output to my setup project.
6. Compile the solution.

Executing the exe file works, but after installation completed, the app doesn't work, did I miss anything?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?  As a test for a dependency problem, copy all the files (but don't overwrite existing) from the bin folder to the location where the installer put the files on the file system (typically somewhere in Program Files or Program Files (x86)).  After you do this, does it work?

Comment: @jglouie thanks for your reply! Really a foolish problem, I missed a file. :(

Comment: **WARNING** Visual Studio Setup projects are a deprecated feature of Visual Studio and were removed in Visual Studio 2012. If you want to create a installer project from scratch, I suggest you look at Wix or a commercial solution like Installshield instead of investing in the Setup Projects. Setup projects are not supported in Team Build and the UI has all kinds of issues.